# How to check screen unlock type of device

Tags: android, broadcast

I have search a lot but my query not match to it, i found the solution for lock and **unlock the phone**

**Like this way I have created my broadcast with the 3 filters which I recieved:**

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "In Method:  ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to find out the way user is unlock screen with it type. if user has unlocked screen by using the **password or pattern or fingerprint or by button**.

So I am not able to get the particular event from which I can get the follow output.

So kindle help to go in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To detect lock pattern I have used below code.So, I think it also help you.you can use **Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED** flag. Show below:-

```
private static boolean CheckPatternSet(Context context)
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    try
    {
        int lockEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED);
        return lockEnabled == 1;
    }
    catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For More understanding you can show below stackoverflow link :-

[Android check if lockscreen is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421039/android-check-if-lockscreen-is-set/46464312#46464312)