# Get secure lock type of android device (Pin, Pattern or Password)

Tags: android, kotlin

I got a problem when I want get current type of lock screen. (***Pin, Pattern or Password***)

I already try:

- `keyguardManager.isDeviceSecure()`: is just return **true** or **false** whether the device is secured with a *PIN*/*Pattern*/*Password* or not.
- `Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED)`: Always crash whether I set lock screen is Pattern or not.

I also checked the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46464312/9114042 but still not working with me.

Comment: Try `DevicePolicyManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare `DevicePolicyManager` have no method for this. Or I missed something?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of [methods like `getPasswordQuality()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#getPasswordQuality(android.content.ComponentName)), though I see that is deprecated on Android 12.